# wbadmin backup all local drives

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, wbadmin

I'm trying to find a one-size fits all `wbadmin` script that I can deploy to a variety of Server 2008 R2 servers.

The catch I'm having is that whilst all of the servers have a C:, some have an E:, some an E: and an F: and some have just an F:.

The following command:

```
wbadmin enable backup -addtarget:\\backup1\Backups -schedule:23:00 -systemState -allCritical -vssFull -user:backupservice@domain.local -password:ladidada -quiet
```

Only backs up the C: and I don't see any options in `wbadmin` to back up all the local drives. And of course, if I try shoot the problem with a machine gun (by adding `-include:c:,d:,e:,f:`...etc) then we get `ERROR - The path specified by 'g:' was not found`.

Please don't tell me that I have to enumarate all the local drives and do it that way. Is there ANY way to tell `wbadmin` to include *all* local drives when backing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a variation that automatically avoids cd/dvd. It deliberately backs up hard drives only.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set remotebackup=\\backupserver\path

for /F "usebackq eol=: skip=1 tokens=1" %%a in (
  `wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get deviceid`
) do (
  set "_drive=%%a:"
  set "_HDL=!_HDL!!_drive:~0,2!,"
)
if "%_HDL:~-1%"=="," (set _HDL=%_HDL:~0,-1%)
if "%_HDL:~-2%"==",:" (set _HDL=%_HDL:~0,-2%)

echo Found: %_HDL%

wbadmin start backup -backuptarget:%remotebackup% -include:!_HDL! -allCritical -vssCopy -quiet -systemState
```

This forms part of a scheduled task which is why `wbadmin start` is used rather than `wbadmin enable`.

The bits of interest here are `"drivetype=3"` and using `usebackq` (required).

Mark's code was helpful in tracking this down.

The if statements remove the last comma or comma and colon if they exist. Couldn't think of an easier way to do this. `%%a` is copied into `_drive` so it can be trimmed to the first 2 characters (C:) using the `:~0,2` syntax.

Comment: Moving the checkmark to your answer because it's more elegant than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

After a heap of mucking around (I hate DOS batching), I've come up with the following. It seems to work well:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f %%I IN (
 'wmic volume get driveletter'
) DO (
  ECHO %%I | FIND ":"
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   echo Failed: %%I
  ) ELSE (
   ECHO %%I | FIND "D:"
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
     IF NOT [!_TEMPVAR!]==[] SET _TEMPVAR=!_TEMPVAR!,
     SET _TEMPVAR=!_TEMPVAR!%%I
    ) ELSE (
      echo Skipping CD-ROM
    )
  )

)

wbadmin enable backup -addtarget:\\backupserver\Backups -schedule:23:00 -systemState -allCritical -vssFull -user:backupservice@domain.local -password:1234password -quiet -include:!_TEMPVAR!
```

A dissection is:

The first part of the batch finds all the drive letters from `wmic volume get driveletter`. It checks to see that each line is actually a valid drive letter (as the output includes some verbose information that we don't need) by checking for the `:` character.

Then, it checks to see if the drive is the `D:` as in my situation these are all optical drives, which cause errors when specified in `wbadmin` and skips them.

Then, it checks to see if the string has content in it. If it does, it suffixes a comma (`,`). If the string is blank, it doesn't do anything.

Then, it goes and appends the drive letter to the the variable.

The, it execudes `wbadmin`:

- `wbadmin enable backup` - specifies that we want to set up a Windows Backup schedule
- `-addtarget:\\enetsbackup1\Backups` - I want to back up to a network location, so I'm specifying it here.
- `-schedule:23:00` - I want the backups to run at 11pm each night
- `-systemState` - I want the system state included for bare metal restores
- `-allCritical` - I want all critical system drives included (this is important because the above script only builds *visible* drive letters. There may be partitions that need backing up in order to boot the server that do not have drive letters)
- `-vssFull` - This is the *only* backup we're doing on this server, so tell Windows Backup to reset the archived bit.
- `-user:backupservice@domain.local` - This is the account that's a member of the Backup Operators group on the domain (and also neeeds to be in the **local** Backup Operators group as well. This is very poorly document by Microsoft)
- `-password:1234password` - The password for the backup service account
- `-quiet` - Do not make any prompts. I'm going to be running this as a startup script in a group policy, so prompts are bad.
- `-include:!_TEMPVAR!` - This is the most critical part. It specifies which drives should be backed up, and includes the string of drives we collected earlier.

And just to confirm it's worked, to check it in the GUI:

[image: Result of wbadmin command]

<sub>Things that can probably be improved: Instead of running from drive letters, the drive GUID might be a smarter idea, because this *won't back up drives that are not mounted with drive letters*. So if you've mounted a disk inside an NTFS partition, or the drive doesn't have a drive letter for whatever reason, it will be skipped.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

while a solution which looked up the list of drives from wmi would be better. If you know you only have e: f: and g: then this will work fine

```
set wbinclude=
if exist e:\*.* set wbinclude=e:\
if exist f:\*.* set wbinclude=%wbinclude% f:\
if exist g:\*.* set wbinclude=%wbinclude% f:\
if not "%wbinclude%"=="" set wbinclude=-includes %wbinclude%

echo wbadmin enable backup -addtarget:\\backup1\Backups -schedule:23:00 -systemState -allCritical -vssFull -user:backupservice@domain.local -password:ladidada -quiet %wbinclude%
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately they're not all the drives, they're all spread over the place. I posted my own script as an answer above which does what you suggested.